# Configure Heartbeat with Elasticsearch to parse Json Result

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've configured elasticsearch, kibana and heartbeat and I do see results under "heartbeat" coming in.

[image]

However whatever processors I add to a monitor I do not see any extra data:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/add-tags.html

```
- type: http
  urls: ["http://localhost:8359/api/heartbeat"]
  schedule: '@every 10s'
  processors:
  - add_tags:
    tags: [web123, production123]
```

I would like to store the actual JSON response which I get when i query my service: http://localhost:8359/api/heartbeat (not just HTTP 200). And would like to show this reponse in Kibana somewhere under "Uptime" section

Sample json response from endpoint:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 2,
    "Messages": [
        "interface not found: MyTestService"
    ],
    "Type": "MyTestService",
    "IsValid": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
  schedule: '@every 2m'
  check.response: 
    status: 200
    json:
      - description: Json Response
        condition:
          equals:
            Status: Ok
```

Where "Status" is one of my json properties that is being returned.